# What to do about unanswered questions that have been edited to completely change the meaning?

Tags: discussion, edits, abuse

The question I'm referring to can be found here: [How to create a suitable for each loop and output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14710703/552438)

As you can see from the revision history, it used to be a completely different question about some jQuery/JavaScript code. It received very little attention, and no answers. It has since been edited (by the original asker) into a completely different question about PHP.

Normally I'd just rollback to the previous revision. However, it has an answer posted to it (answering the new question, not the one it was originally asking), as well as a bounty attached, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

What steps should be taken to resolve this kind of situation? Is rolling back to a previous revision - making subsequent answers invalid (through no fault of the person answering) - the correct response? Since there were no answers to the original question, can it simply be left in its new state?

Comment: This guy seems to have a habit of doing that, and is using it as a shortcut to post bounties on new questions.

Comment: @WesleyMurch life imitating meta? [Bounty ready reserve questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161392)

Comment: 10K users might want to check this "answer" out too, it does appear the user may have multiple accounts: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14305295/398242 From the code posted and writing style I think it's true, mods might want to take a look.

Comment: Closely related: [What should be done with a closed question that has been completely rewritten?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165199)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do nothing.

It would have been a different case if the original question had answers, but in this case, no harm done.

Answer (score 3):

In my eyes (and actions on the rare occurance this happens). If:

- The Original Asker makes the edit
- It is a complete overhaul of the question (tags corrected, title adjusted, etc)
- There are no answers
- There are no comments

then I would leave it alone. The asker has simply asked a different question without raising his question count or removing information about a problem.

If:

- The question has answers
- The question has related comments
- The question has been voted on

then I would roll the question back to the original edition (that got answers. Last edit pertaining to valid answers)