# Reopening closed question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, up-votes, post-ban, reopen-closed

I would like to know if the questions that are "off-topic" or "not a real question" can possibly be reopened by re-editing to change the title and question so far. Take a look at my question I've made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909850/rss-bug-missing-id). As you can see, the old question referred to if RSS can be created using LibGDX and I replaced with a new question that tells the problem about the sample RSS Android project not working. Is it possible that if I change the topic and question, votes will up back from -1 to 0 and the question voted open?

Comment: Anything is possible, but why did you completely change the question? It's okay given that there were no answers, but if there would have been, then completely changing your question would be inappropriate.

Comment: I cannot be able to create questions again at _Stackoverflow_ since the ASK QUESTION button is disabled until you either revise the question it or gain at least an upvote so that you can ask question again. The only option I can just in case is to replace the old question with the new one. It's like recycling a new question in case if the ASK QUESTION button is disabled due to some reasons.

Comment: So you're saying you're question-banned?

Comment: Yes. I decided to revise and change a new question to reopen it. If I use the useless ASK QUESTION due to violations/limitations, why not replacing your old question through editing for a new one?

Comment: I wish I accept both Bart and slugster's answers since both them are correct. However, I'll check on Bart since I used the flag so that I'll be question-banned free again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you essentially seem to be asking is

> If I'm question-banned, can I completely change an existing closed question into a good on-topic one (provided there were no answers) and have it reopened?

In that particularly narrow case, and provided that there are no answers or other contributions of value you would invalidate by changing your question, I do not have a problem with it.

Once you've completed your good question, flag it for moderator attention and clearly explain the situation to them. They might then decide to reopen it. (Or they may refuse, if it's still a poor question). This is no guarantee however that you will have the downvotes reversed. Your new question will have to be of significant quality for that to happen.

In general however (even as a question-banned user) you should not completely change your question. Questions should be improved. And if you have a different question, you should ask a new question once you're allowed to. However, given this particular scenario, an exception could possibly be made.

Comment: Recycling a new question is okay as long as there are no answers in that case, right?

Comment: "Questions should be improved" - this can also be interpreted as "My question should grow based on given answers so far", which is not always appreciated by those who answer.

Comment: @Jack Say what now?

Comment: For instance, question starts simple and as the answers come in, new "sub" questions start to get added. In a narrow view, that could also be considered improving; but that kind of improving may not be so well liked.

Comment: @Jack We're dealing here with a user who has a question-ban. I'm not advocating help-vampirism here. Such banned users usually get the advice to improve their existing questions. Not to completely change them. That is the situation we're discussing.

Comment: Okay, guess I misunderstood then, didn't realize the user in question had a question-ban :)

Comment: @DavidDimalanta That is indeed my opinion. However, keep in mind that it's an exceptional situation. In any other case I would advocate against doing that. And still you should focus on improving your existing content where possible. But if you can clean up the junk by creating a good question, while doing no harm as a side-effect, I don't see a particular problem with it in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

(Note: at the time I did this answer it wasn't known that you were question banned.)

---

Do not morph your question - that is a guaranteed way to annoy prospective answerers very quickly. If you have a new question then start a new question. Don't change an old question into a completely different new question.

By all means try and tidy up your closed question - once you do flag it for moderator attention and explain the change you have made (but don't waste the mod's time, make sure your changes are good). Keep in mind that they may still dismiss your flag - tidying up a question is no guarantee of it getting reopened. Alternatively you can vote to reopen if you have sufficient privileges, but there is also no guarantee with that approach either.

The easiest thing to do is review your question several times before posting it. If you were looking to answer your question, what would you want to see included in it, how would you expect it to be formatted?

Comment: So you're telling me that revising through editing is good but making a new question means making a new question and not recycling the old ones?

Comment: @DavidDimalanta That is correct - by all means edit the old question *but make sure it is fundamentally the same question*. Your example question has undergone a radical change but it seems to be ultimately the same - I would think it's a borderline case where maybe it would have been better to open a new question and include a reference link back to the old question with a note that you've totally rephrased it. Some may not like that approach though, it depends on how big the change is.

Comment: @slugster I [asked about this recently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166817/186991), and the general response was that if a question has no answers, changing it entirely isn't a big deal.